# Event Pattern in EventBridge Rule for DMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms, amazon-cloudtrail, aws-event-bridge

I have a DMS task, and I want to create a Event Based EventBridge Rule when the DMS Replication Task starts a load. My initial Event Pattern was as follows and it triggered the target:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.dms"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["dms.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["StartReplicationTask"]
  }
}
```

But I need this event to trigger specifically for only one DMSReplicationTask and when the task stops running. Following is the updated Event Pattern that I have:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.dms"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["dms.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["StopReplicationTask"],
    "responseElements": {
      "replicationTask": {
        "replicationTaskIdentifier": ["sample-full-load"],
        "status": ["stopping"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I checked the Cloud Trail event and it seems to match the arguments I am passing here. But the target is not getting invoked with this.

I am pretty new to this. Any thoughts.?

Comment: If the event rule is ok, then maybe there is something wrong with target. Can you provide its details? Does events have permissinos to invoke it?

Comment: There is no issue with the target. Its just a lambda function and whenever I change the Event Pattern back to "StartReplicationTask", It seems to be working.